# Is there a possibility to enabel/disable send datagrams in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, winsock

I would like to send data by using sendto() function in Windows.
I want to control the sending data by a dedicated function.
The idea behind is not to reprogram the memory queue behavior of sendto().

The question is:
Is there a possibility/Windows-Function to enable or disable transmitting data of sendto() in Windows by a dedicated function?

Best Regards.

Comment: Yes, and it is called a *firewall* ;-)  Seriously, you cannot *programably* block `sendto()` from sending data (unless you drop down to the driver layer and write your own filtering driver to block network traffic).  If you don't want `sendto()` to send data, don't call it to begin with.

Comment: `if(!disable_sendto) sendto(...)`

Comment: Hello Remy, thank you for your answer. The Idea was, that if there is a switch in ioctl (or any other function) for enable/disable transmitting data, how to use respectively what is the name of the function. So the sendto() function can normally work and be called, but the switch can control if the datagrams will be transmitted. If such a function would be available I do not need to code a queue with the same functionality which is already implemented in sendto(). I hope I could show what was the idea behind the question.